# Adding delay after vuex state changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add some delay to transitioning out of an element when the value - `v-if` directive binds to - changes from `true` to `false`. I am using Vuex to maintain the state of `isLoading` so that it is used in other components.

So I have an API call that sets `this.$store.state.isLoading` to true while waiting for response, and false once response is received. But the problem is that API response is almost instant and the progress bar only flashes for a split second.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-progress v-if="isLoading" :max="max">
      <b-progress-bar :value="count"></b-progress-bar>
    </b-progress>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0,
            max: 100
        }
    },
    computed: {
        isLoading () {
            return this.$store.state.isLoading;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Is this the right thinking by adding delay after the state is changed? If so, what is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the delay right after your API call, assuming you have a mutation named `updateIsLoading` to update the `isLoading` state.

```js
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    // do something with your data
    setTimeout(() => this.$store.commit('updateIsLoading'), 1000)
  })
  .catch(...)
```

If you need to set the delay once and for all, one solution is to create an action, and then dispatch the action after you get response from the API call.

```js
actions: {
  updateIsLoading({ commit }) {
    setTimeout(() => commit('updateIsLoading'), 1000)
  }
}
```

---

If you really want to do this in your component, you can setup a watcher and update a local `isLoading` variable after some delay:

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0,
            max: 100,
            isLoading: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        loading () {
            return this.$store.state.isLoading;
        }
    },
    watch: {
      loading(newVal, oldVal) {
        setTimeout(() => this.isLoading = newVal, 1000)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: But my api calls are situated in multiple other components. I am trying to use the same loader for all.